# Tkinter .after() method going faster than it should

Tags: python, tkinter

I been working on a simple Tkinter Gui in which a timer gets involved. The thing is that the timer goes faster than the milliseconds specified in the `.after()` method. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
import time
from tkinter import *
seconds = 604800

FONT = ("Arial", 24)
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.attributes('-topmost', True)
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window.title("Sandbox Crypto")
window.configure(bg='red')
seconds = 604800

def gui():
    text = StringVar()

    def substract_seconds():
        global seconds
        seconds -=1

    while seconds > 0:
        mins, secs = divmod(seconds, 60)
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(days,hours,mins, secs)
        text.set(timer)
        Time_label = Label(window, textvariable=text, bg='red', fg='white', font=FONT)
        Time_label.grid()
        Time_label.place(x=10, y=300)
        Time_label.update()

        Time_label.after(1000, substract_seconds)

    window.mainloop()


gui()
```

The strange thing here is that i investigated the `.after()` method common errors and most of them were related to the method actually going slower than it should. One of my theories is that is an error related to the CPU speed because the speed of the clock varies through the time. What I infer from this is that sometimes it goes faster and then it slows down and continue going faster.

Comment: The function is not guaranteed to run at exactly the requested speed. It can be off by many milliseconds. Is this really your actual code? You're calling `after` in a while loop, meaning you may be calling it several times a second.

Comment: Likely calling it thousands of times a second and bogging the `mainloop` down keeping track of them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used while loop, there is new scheduled task created to update the `seconds` in every iteration.

You don't need the while loop at all, below is modified `gui()`:

```py
def gui():
    text = StringVar()
    Time_label = Label(window, textvariable=text, bg='red', fg='white', font=FONT)
    Time_label.place(x=10, y=300)

    def countdown(seconds=seconds):
        mins, secs = divmod(seconds, 60)
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(days,hours,mins, secs)
        text.set(timer)

        if seconds > 0:
            Time_label.after(1000, countdown, seconds-1)

    countdown() # start the count down
    window.mainloop()
```